# How to post a video file from React native camera component to Django

Tags: django, react-native, video-processing

How can I post a video file (which format) from React native to a Django application so that after processing it the transformed video file is  returned to the React native Component?

In my Camera Component

```
try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/my-post-view/', {videoSource});

      setApivideo(response.data);
                
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
}
```

In My Django View

```
def my_post_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    video_uri = request.data.get('videoUri')
 
//Im Processing video Here actually its not reading video_uri -
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
//After processing the video 

   return HttpResponse({'processedData': cap})
```

I tried with the code above using POST http method but I'm confused about how to post a video source file and get the transformed video file back to  to my react native component.